# Function returning Promise in ternary expression not working React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I have a function called `permCheck()` which will resolve to true or false based on some logic. I need to take the value from this and utilize it in a ternary expression to change the content the user sees. However, it seems to always be returning the true part of the expression, even when `permCheck()` is false.

Here is the `permCheck()` function which does properly return `true` or `false`:

```
function permCheck(res) {
  let isMember;
  return axios.get(window.location.origin + "/username").then((res) => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://api.endpoint.com/ismember/" +
          res.data
      )
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data; // This will be true or false
      });
    isMember = res.data;
    return isMember;
  });
}
```

Then in the return for my react app I am trying to change the content based on the `permCheck` function. This is where it seems to always just default to the first part of the ternary expression. As you can see I even have a `console.log` in the ternary expression which is properly returning true or false.

```
return (
<div className="ui">
  <AppLayout
    content={
      permCheck().then((a) => {
        console.log("IN TERNARY: " + a);
        Promise.resolve(a);
      })
        ? appContent
        : accessDenied
    } // Here we expect true or false from permCheck()
    navigation={<ServiceNavigation />}
    notifications={<FlashMessage />}
    breadcrumbs={<Breadcrumbs />}
    contentType="table"
    tools={Tools}
    headerSelector="#navbar"
    stickyNotifications={true}
  />
</div>
```

);

Comment: You have an expression like PROMISE ? appContent : accessDenied. PROMISE is not falsey (it's not undefined or null or 0, etc) so it defaults to the first value of ternary operator regardless of what your permCheck function returns.

Comment: Your permCheck function is equivalent (as return value) to

function permCheck(res) {
  let isMember;
  return axios.get(window.location.origin + "/username").then((res) => {
    isMember = res.data;
    return isMember;
  });
}

Comment: @Virtuoz What would be the best way to get past this? I am not sure how else to return this.

Comment: Use a state variable (`useState` or `this.state`) to keep track of the process, and update it with the result once the promise is ready (`.then()`). Until then, render some loading spinner, or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check for a value, that you will only receive in the future, so you can't just unwrap your promise.

Instead, you should use a state variable to store the result, and rerender your component, once it's available. Until then, you can render some loading effect/spinner/text, to inform the user.

Assuming you're using a functional component, it'd look like this:

```
function component(){
  const [permission, setPermission] = useState(undefined)
  //Use `useEffect` to prevent recurring checking
  useEffect(() => {
    permCheck().then((a) => {
      //Update (rerender) the component with the permission info
      setPermission(a)
    })
  }, [])
  return (
  <div className="UI">
    <AppLayout
      content={
        //When this runs for the first time, `permission` will be `undefined` (meaning 'not available'), so handle this case as well:
        permission === undefined
          ? 'Checking permission, hang on...'
          : permission
            ? appContent
            : accessDenied
      }
      navigation={<ServiceNavigation />}
      notifications={<FlashMessage />}
      breadcrumbs={<Breadcrumbs />}
      contentType="table"
      tools={Tools}
      headerSelector="#navbar"
      stickyNotifications={true}
    />
  </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: That's what I was missing... thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I write an answer because my comment is illegible.
I think you function `permCheck` is equivalent to

```
function permCheck(res) { 
  let isMember; 
  return axios.get(window.location.origin + "/username").then((res) => { 
    isMember = res.data; 
    return isMember; 
  }); 
}
```

the part

```
axios.get(
        "https://api.endpoint.com/ismember/" +
          res.data
      )
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data; // This will be true or false
      });
```

has no effects in the return value.

Here an example. As you can see, the resource logged is the first one not the second

```js
function permCheck(res) {
  let isMember;
  return axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then((res) => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data; // This will be true or false
      });
    isMember = res.data;
    return isMember;
  });
}

permCheck().then(data=>console.log(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The 2nd axios.get uses a value from the first one to call an API we use which returns true or false. That is the axios call which actually is providing the true/false.

Comment: but you don't return that value in your function.

Comment: You can't return a variable from a promise like that! You'll get another promise!